# Passenger nginx install doesn't come with a service to restart nginx?

Tags: nginx, phusion-passenger

How do you restart nginx on a Ubuntu passenger-nginx install?

I installed passenger, and then it automatically installed nginx. However there's no command to restart nginx anywhere. I tried service restart nginx and /etc/init.d/nginx restart and no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add it to init.d if you're more comfortable with using it.

http://wiki.nginx.org/Nginx-init-ubuntu